# Monitor of a machine that I remote to turns off

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I remote to my work machine but when I come back to work that machines monitor is off. Monitor power is on and machine is on.  I have to reboot my PC.  Why?

My work machine runs Windows7 64bit.    My home machine runs Windows7 x86.

I'm connecting using Cisco VPN client first and then using windows Remote Desktop Connection.

I have two monitors at work and only one at home. The main monitor is the one that is off.

Comment: Operating system? Remote desktop version?  These things would help us with your question.

Comment: What are you using to remote into the machine. Remote Desktop, VNC? What kind of machine is this? Is it a laptop, desktop? What are the power settings?

Comment: And what do you mean by off?  Is the power off?  Does cycling the power off and back on not bring it back up?  Does it not "wake up" when you move the mouse or hit a key?

Comment: @BBlake The power is on. Turning monitor on and off doesn't help.  Moving the mouse or hitting a key doesn't help.

Comment: Tried win+p ? Perhaps the system is assuming that you are connecting to a separate display when you remote in... windows sometimes does funky things like that.

Comment: @Krono what is win+p?  Also I forgot to mention that I have two monitors at work. The main monitor is the one that is off.

Comment: @meddle it is the shortcut that switches between use of displays.  press and hold the windows button and then press p to switch between use of right monitor, left monitor, duplicate, and extend

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue before with Teamviewer. Try updating your video drivers that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. Check your power settings to make sure your computer is not set to sleep or turn off after a specified period of time.